# trying to stop multiple activations

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to activate a relay when the correct card is being read by the RFID reader. But the problem is when I don't pull the card from the reader the loop goes continuously.

```
void loop() 
{
  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  Serial.print("UID tag :");
  String content= "";
  byte letter;
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) 
  {
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Message : ");
  content.toUpperCase();
  if (content.substring(1) == "A7 5E 0F 3C") //change here the UID of the card/cards that you want to give access
  {
    Serial.println("Authorized access");
    Serial.println();
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);

  }

 else   {
    Serial.println(" Access denied");
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with the loop goes continuously? loop is called continuously by design.

Comment: Seems like method `PICC_IsNewCardPresent` does not do exactly what you intend, (trigger only once). Or you have the card not close enough, so that it's interpreted as "present - away - present" and retriggers.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the card one time, you can wait till the card is removed before reading it again. Give this code a try:

```
void loop() 
{
  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  Serial.print("UID tag :");
  String content= "";
  byte letter;
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) 
  {
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
     Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Message : ");
  content.toUpperCase();
  if (content.substring(1) == "A7 5E 0F 3C") //change here the UID of the card/cards that you want to give access
  {
    Serial.println("Authorized access");
    Serial.println();
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);

  }

  else {
    Serial.println(" Access denied");
  }

  /* wait till the card is removed */
  while(mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
      delay(100);
  }
}
```